# Sharing Redis among services

Tags: redis, microservices

I have a use case in which `Microservice A` has to do some heavy computation periodically and stores the result in Cache (redis) - something like k8s cron job.

`Microservice B` depends on the Cache written by A.(B only reads. never modifies cache).

But it looks like db is being shared here. Is this a good design?
([This aws doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/data-caching-across-microservices-in-a-serverless-architecture/#:%7E:text=Caches%20reduce%20latency%20and%20service,stores%20a%20subset%20of%20data.&text=Though%20Lambda%20functions%20are%20short,microservice%20to%20avoid%20backend%20calls) shows 2 different services using same redis)

Comment: If you want to limit the access to Redis, you can make `B` support a `get` rpc call, and `A` calls `B::get` to get data from Redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of redis should be treated as ephemeral, not permanent. It's a cache. There is nothing wrong with your design *as long as your microservices, especially Microservice B, behave gracefully if they do not find what they expect in redis.*

Answer (score -3):

This is actually a very common practice in projects using Redis (for example its the exact way you setup Redis to act as a message broker. One end writes the message and the other reads it.)

Databases are meant do be shared, especially in the modern days where a program can consist of hundreds of micro-parts.

You shouldn't have any issues related to Redis, BUT you **HAVE** to implement a fallback mechanism for Micro-service B, to handle the case in which no value is found, for example using a timeout and then read again, or getting some default value and using that.

Comment: Hi - is this statement `Databases are meant do be shared` really correct? Because it an anto-pattern Also you are confusing caching data with message queue. I do understand message queues are shared among services.

Comment: Hello - Yes databases are definitely meant to be shared! Imagine how many copies of client data you would have if every office in every building of a company had its own mariadb running! And imagine all the problems when they wouldnt all be on the same page when changing stuff! Now compare the offices with microservices. Also yes messaging and caching are different things, but they work the same way amd it was a good example for the issue.